# Singular matrix is similar to matrix with zero row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a singular $n \times n$ complex matrix. Does there exist a matrix $B$ similar to $A$ such that $B$ has a zero row?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$

In other words:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and $A : V\to V$ a singular linear map. Does there exist a basis for $V$ such that its matrix representation in that basis has a zero row?

**First attempt:**

Let $\dim V = n$. $A$ is not surjective so $\Ima A \ne V$. Let $M \leq V$ be a direct complement of $\Ima A$. Pick a basis $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$ for $M$, and $\{x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n\} \subseteq V$ such that $\{Ax_{m+1}, \ldots, Ax_n\}$ is a basis for $\Ima A$. Since $M \dot{+}\Ima A = V$, $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m, Ax_{m+1}, \ldots, Ax_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Let $x \in V$.

$$Ax = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_ib_i + \sum_{i=m+1}^n \gamma_iAx_i \implies \underbrace{A\left(x - \sum_{i=m+1}^n\right)}_{\in\Ima A} = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_ib_i}_{\in M}$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_ib_i \in M \cap \Ima A$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_ib_i = 0$ which implies $\alpha_i = 0, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$, because of linear independence of $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$.
So:

$$Ax = \sum_{i=m+1}^n \gamma_iAx_i$$

This implies that the first $m$ rows of the matrix representation of $A$ are null rows.

**Second attempt:**

We shall show that $A \sim B$, where $B$ has a zero column. Then, $B^T$ has a zero row, and since $B^T \sim B$, we have $A \sim B^T$.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$

Take $0\ne x \in \Ker A$, and let $\{x, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ containing $x$. Then, since $Ax = 0$, the first row of the matrix representation of $A$ is a zero column.

Are these proofs correct? Is there a shorter/more illustrative proof?

Comment: Yes. Take the Jordan Canonical Form. Singular matrices must have zero as one of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Vim It seems I missed the obvious solution. For real matrices, I suppose we could take the real Jordan Form.